# How to take a car that makes a race challenging?

Tags: gran-turismo-4

In Gran Turismo 4 for PS2, I play the Gran Turismo mode. When I take part in a race tournament, it often goes like this:

- Buy a car which is allowed to drive in this tournament
- Start the tournament
- Recognise that the car is far to fast (winning is easy) or to slow (winning impossible)
- Buy a new car or tune the car
- Try again - race is still to easy/too hard
- Tuning the car again
- Try again, and again, and again...

I repeat the last steps often until I find a setup for my car so that the race is challenging, but possible to win. Unfortunately, this process takes very long (yesterday I spent 2 hours with it!), costly and annoying. Another problem is that the opponent cars are not always the same, so taking part twice in a race tournament could be easier one time and more challenging the other time.

Is there a way to know in "advance" which car and setup I should take so that the race is challenging, but not impossible? Is this problem fixed in future Gran Turismo versions (Gran Turismo 5)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My gut response, based mainly on my many hours with GT3, is that you need to really learn the tracks. I mean **really** learn them, like a real race driver would. Identify corners you're slow on and fix them. If you can race against your own ghost replay, do that. If there's a whole track lap license for a track you're racing on, can you get a gold trophy on it?

You might feel that winning is impossible with your car, but it might not be. If the car has the power to keep up with the other cars on the straight at the start of the race, you can probably win the race through sheer skill and track knowledge. Work hard, and you'll get there.

Also, try the races that only allow a small number of car models, or ideally, one type of car. This helps to level the playing field, as long as you resist the urge to upgrade parts and instead work on your track knowledge.

**EDIT :** In GT5 each race menu provides a list of the "typical" cars you'll be racing against, and their power rating. This can help you to choose a similar car, if that's what you're after.

Comment: *"If the car has the power to keep up with the other cars on the straight at the start of the race, you can probably win the race through sheer skill and track knowledge."* - That's the problem I have. Sometimes my car is far to fast, the next time (driving with the same car) it is far too slow. However, +1 for the other hints, thanks :)

Comment: So your car seems to change speed on different attempts of the same race? Or the other cars are changing?

Comment: The other cars are changing.

Comment: I guess that's because the opponent choice is randomly generated for each race. I'm not sure there's much you can do about that, apart from continually restarting the race until it looks fair. At least GT5 seems to be improved in that area.

Comment: That's nice to hear, thank you for the information!